# Print last digits of an integer gradually?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, logic

I am trying to to print the last digits of a user inputted integer.
For example if the user inputs 5432
my output is
2
32
432
5432.
I have managed to write the code for this using a while loop, however i don't understand why my loop does not terminate, please help me terminate it?

```
void main()
{
    //declare variables
    int input, output, modulu = 10;
    //read input from user
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> input;
    int test = input % modulu;   // test checks if all the number has been printed
                                 //disect number
    while (test > 0);
    {
        output = input % modulu;
        modulu = modulu * 10;
        cout << endl << output << endl;
        test = input % modulu;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your while loop doesn't terminate because test never takes a value less or equal to zero. You might want to modify your loop condition.

Comment: @oladodja gbasamassi, could you please  what to?I've tried other conditions and haven't succeeded

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your first problem is here:

```
while (test > 0);
```

The `;` terminates the while-statement and the code will stay in the while forever. In other words - all the code below is never executed. Remove the `;`

Your second problem is the way you handle `test` - don't take modulo but divide by 10 instead. Like this:

```
int main()
{
    //declare variables
    int input, output, modulu = 10;
    //read input from user
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> input;
    int test = input;  // <------------- Just make test equal to the input
    while (test > 0)   // <------------- The ; removed
    {
        output = input % modulu;
        modulu = modulu * 10;
        cout << endl << output << endl;
        test = test / 10;       // <----------- Divide by 10
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that the above code has some problems with zeros, e.g. `1001` will output `1` `1` `1` `1001` instead of `1` `01` `001` `1001`.

You can fix that by a completely different approach using `string`instead of `int`

Like:

```
int main()
{
    //declare variables
    string input;

    //read input from user
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << input << endl;
    int size = input.size();
    int tmp = size;
    while (tmp >= 0)
    {
        for (int t = tmp; t < size; t ++) cout << input[t];
        cout << endl;
        --tmp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`test` is always > 0 for any input > 0

you can achieve the same with different loop:

```
int input, modulu = 1;
cout << "Please enter a number: ";
cin >> input;
do {
    modulu *= 10;
    cout << endl << (input % modulu) << endl;
} while ((input % modulu) != input);
```

Comment: Thanks! this almost works, however it doesn't print the first digit 
void main()
{
 //declare variables
 int input, output, modulu = 10;
 //read input from user
 cout << "Please enter a number: ";
 cin >> input;
 int test;  // test checks if all the number has been printed
         //disect number
 do
 {
  output = input % modulu;
  modulu = modulu * 10;
  cout << endl << output << endl;
  test = input % modulu;
 } while (test != input);
}

Comment: @FaresAlGhazy I don't know why you've corrupted mine working code and ask why it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Just
test = input / modulu;
instead of test = input % modulu;

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is a semicolon after the while statement.

```
while (test > 0);
               ^^^
```

So the loop is infinite provided that the last digit of the entered number is not equal to 0.

However if you  remove the semicolon the condition is invalid because `test == 0` only in the case when the last digit is equal to 0.

Take into acount that `main` in C++ shall have return type `int`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        const unsigned int Base = 10;

        std::cout << "Please enter a non-negative number (0-exit): ";

        unsigned int x;

        if ( !( std::cin >> x ) || x == 0 ) break;

        unsigned int y = x;
        unsigned int modulo = 1;

        do
        {
            modulo *= Base;

            std::cout << x % modulo << std::endl;
        } while ( y /= Base );

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If for example to enter

```
123456789
0
```

then the output will look like

```
Please enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 123456789
9
89
789
6789
56789
456789
3456789
23456789
123456789

Please enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 0
```